How the annuity payment is computed here?
How the payment of $-89,200.13per annum is computed here?⇒ Annuity

Note: If you uncheck hide data table, data table will be shown.
Using Fin.Cal package in 'R', I got the approximately same answer.

pv.annuity(0.006666667,360,-4000,0)

545134

pmt(0.0066666667,60,0,545134,0)

-7419.125

-7419.125*12

-89029.5

You will have to tell us what values you selected for the 9 different inputs.

@mhoran_psprep, Input data is visible after clicking on 'Annuity'.

When I click the link all the fields are blank.

Right -- stored values are in cookies in the questioner's machine. I'm not sure "how is it computed" can be answered except by pointing at the formulas in the spreadsheet, unless you are asking about the general principles behind annuities in general...

An annuity is just a loan in reverse - instead of borrowing a lump sum and paying it off over time, you invest a lump sum and they pay it back to you over time (with interest). Annuities can either pay for a fixed time or until you die (in which case they base the payment on your statistical life expectancy).
So how much would you need to invest to get paid $4,000 per month for 30 years at 8% annual interest? Any loan calculator (or Excel) can do that math easily:

Note that the Excel formula is =PV(I/12,N*12,PMT)
Now, how much do you have to save at 8% annual interest to get $548,768 in 5 years (when you are buying the annuity?). Again, a loan calculator or Excel can do that easily:

Where the Excel formula for the monthly payment is =PMT(I/12,N*12,PV,PMT)
You can find formulas for both of these calculations by searching for "loan payment formula".
There are probably some slightly different assumptions in their calculator (annual vs monthly compounding, payments at the beginning or end of each period, etc.) that change the result slightly, but that's the general idea.
